# Why is the cache storage in Google Chrome developer tools empty in offline mode?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I am using a service worker in order to cache and fetch files.

The files are getting cached in **online** mode but when I shift to **offline** mode, the cache storage in Chrome developer tools is empty. I am not able to make out what is the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

```
const cacheName = 'myCacheVersion1';
var filesToCache = [
    '/',
    '/service-worker/offline-page.html',
    '/service-worker/sw.js'
]

const offlineUrl = 'https://gmc-test.mytrah.com/service-worker/offline-page.html';

this.addEventListener('install', event => {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache){
            console.log(offlineUrl);
            return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
        })
            .then(() => self.skipWaiting())
    );
})

self.addEventListener('activate', function(e) {
    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Activate');
    e.waitUntil(
        caches.keys().then(function(keyList) {
            return Promise.all(keyList.map(function(key) {
                if (key !== cacheName) {
                    console.log('[ServiceWorker] Removing old cache', key);

                    return caches.delete(key);
                }
            }));

        })
    );
    return self.clients.claim();
});

this.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    console.log(event.request);
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(event.request).catch(() => caches.match(event.request))
    )
});`
```

The above displayed is service worker code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the expected outcome?

Comment: @noogui the outcome should be like, the files should be cached in offline mode too. As i already said, it is getting cached in online mode, but as soon as i shift to offline mode, the cache storage becomes empty. The expected outcome should be, the cached files will be displayed when I am in offline mode or when network is not available.

Comment: Sounds to me like a Chrome bug. You should file an issue with them.

Comment: I don't see that behavior in Chrome. Did your site pass a Lighthouse audit?

Comment: Seeing the same behaviour in chrome version 70.0.3538.110

Comment: It seems that it only works if you have the current specific url cached. I was trying to always serve `index.html` for a range of urls for my SPA.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem is that you're caching the files correctly, but when you're offline and the service worker is trying to fetch the precached assets, you actually request them from the network:

```
this.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    console.log(event.request);
    event.respondWith(
        fetch(event.request).catch(() => caches.match(event.request))
    )
});
```

You should do something like this:

```
event.respondWith(
    caches.open(cacheName).then((cache) => {
        return cache.match(evt.request).then((response) => {
            // get from the cache, then make a network request if theres no cache
            return response || fetch(event.request);
        } 
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

I was facing similar issue while working on the service worker. The moment I marked the network as offline, the cache used to disappear from the Cache Storage. The issue this happened is because I had kept my service worker file inside the `javascripts` folder. Just like OP has placed inside a `service-worker` folder. Now the above leads to the scope issue.

---

### Fix

Hence, in-order to make your service worker work (no pun intended), **you need to move your service worker file to the root dir** (emphasis on security while you do so).

---

### Documentation

As [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#Why_is_my_service_worker_failing_to_register) quotes:

> The service worker will only catch requests from clients under the service worker's scope.
>
> The max scope for a service worker is the location of the worker.

You can also set a scope by passing the `scope` path while registering your Service Worker like

```
navigator.serviceWorker
  .register('/cache-worker.js', {
    scope: '/some-folder' 
    /* but again, you can never put your service worker inside a dir and 
       try to set a scope which is outside of the service worker dir. 
       It can always be at a lower level than where your service worker file resides..
  })

...
```